# Ionic Storage update value which is object

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’ve been looking for a while now in the forum, but can’t get it to work.

Basically I set my data using

```
this.storage.set('data', [
  {id:1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name:'b'}
])
```

How do I edit the name of id:2 without overwriting the array? I’ve done some get and set but end up overwriting the entire object.

I have tried one of the solutions here in so but end up overwriting the object

```
    // Get the entire data
this.storage.get('data').then(valueStr => {

  let value = valueStr[1];

   // Modify just that property
   value.name = "hello";

   // Save the entire data again
   this.storage.set('pets', JSON.stringify(value));

   console.log(valueStr)
});
```

Hopefully I got some help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
this.storage.get('data').then(valueStr => {

  let value = valueStr;

   // Modify just that property
   value[1].name = "hahaha"; <--- need to specify index

   // Save the entire data again
   this.storage.set('pets', value);

   console.log(valueStr)
});
```